# Number of possible solutions given a specific input

Tags: combinatorics, systems-of-equations, recreational-mathematics

Given a set of positive integers $N_1,N_2,...N_N$ and a function $f(x)$ where $f(x)=ℤ$ for all $x \in ℤ$.
There exist solutions of the form $n_1,n_2,...n_N$ where $n_i \ge 1$ and $n_i \in ℤ$  subject to the constraint:
$$\sum_{i=1}^k n_i < f\left(\sum_{i=1}^k N_i\right)$$

question: for a set $N_1,N_2,...N_N$; what is the total number of different solutions?

Whilst i have been able to manually calculate all comibnations for specific sets i have been unable to figure out a method which doesn't require brute force.
I have been able to determine that the number of combinations is always less than:
$$\prod_{i=1}^N f\left(\left(\sum_{k=1}^i N_k \right) - i\right)$$

Comment: [Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question](https://e.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391) + [please avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933).

Comment: Since the constraint only depends on $f(\sum N_k)$, the $N_k$'s themselves, and even their sum, are irrelevant. Are the unknowns $n_k$ supposed to be positive integers? Or non-negative integers?